# What does "two hundred kilos if she was a kilo" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

In Wallace's "Infinite Jest", he describes a girl as being "two hundred kilos if she was a kilo". Is she two hundred kilos or isn't she ... ?

Comment: Possible answer on English.SE: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/origin-of-hes-6-feet-tall-if-hes-an-inch

Comment: Apparently a duplicate can only mean "a duplicate of something else on ELL.SE" but this is one on English.SE, so I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Just my opinion: It's not truly a "duplicate" if the question is answered on another exchange. It's completely up to you if you want leave it open here; I can close it if you think the matter is settled, but it might be helpful for learners around the globe to have this question on this exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiom **"it's X if it's Y"**, where Y is much smaller than X, like

- "She was two hundred kilos if she was a kilo"
- "He's six feet tall if he's an inch"
- "It's twenty miles if it's a yard"

is an informal, emphatic way of saying **I am certain that X.**

You could think of it as a way of saying, for example, "I am as certain that she weighs 200 kilos as I am that she weighs at least one kilo (and since she definitely weighs at least one kilo, I am therefore certain that she weighs 200 kilos)."

See this discussion on English.SE:  [Origin of “he's 6 feet tall if he's an inch”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/origin-of-hes-6-feet-tall-if-hes-an-inch)

Comment: I think this is an example of a snowclone.